# How to read file names and versions from XML file and add them into dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

### I have a Xml file and file names and versions in file tags..... i want to read all file names and their corresponding versions and then want to add them into a dictionary

```
<application name="AutoUpdator" url="\\server\setups\AutoUpdator" version="1.1.0.0" updatedOn= "9-6-2013">
<InfoConfigFile name="InfoFile" version="1.1.0.0" />
<file name="Core0.txt" version="1.1.0.0" source="\\server\setups\AutoUpdator\1.1.0.0\bin\Core0.txt"/>
<file name="Core1.txt" version="1.1.0.0" source="\\server\setups\AutoUpdator\1.1.0.0\bin\Core1.txt"/>
<file name="Core2.txt" version="1.1.0.0" source="\\server\setups\AutoUpdator\1.1.0.0\bin\Core2.txt"/>
<file name="Core3.txt" version="1.1.0.0" source="\\server\setups\AutoUpdator\1.1.0.0\bin\Core3.txt"/>
<file name="Core4.txt" version="1.0.0.0" source="\\server\setups\AutoUpdator\1.0.0.0\bin\Core4.txt"/>
<file name="Core5.txt" version="1.0.0.0" source="\\server\setups\AutoUpdator\1.0.0.0\bin\Core5.txt"/>
</files>
</application>
```

Comment: so what's the poblem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). Start by adding the following `using` statement at the top of your C# file if you don't have it already...

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Then you can load the XML file into an [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) like this...

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\path\to\your\file.xml");
```

Or if you already have the XML in string variable, you can do this...

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
```

If there cannot be duplicate file names in your XML, you can get your `Dictionary` like this...

```
var dictionary = document.Root
                         .Element("files")
                         .Elements("file")
                         .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("name").Value,
                                       x => x.Attribute("version").Value);
```

Comment: i didn't get the purpose of using "x => x" here

Comment: That's a lambda expression. You can read more about them at [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx). They are a key part of LINQ programming, you can read more about that here: [LINQ (Language-Integrated Query)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx)

Comment: thnx davmos ... :)
can we solve this problem using Xmlreader?

Comment: No problem, Amarjeet. I've rarely used `XmlReader` since 'LINQ to XML' was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

C# has a fairly extensive XML library available.

The class you are likely looking for is called XmlReader and documentation is available here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.71).aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548

Each line in the sample text you posted is called an *element* in XML , so as you read through the documentation in the above links, the XmlNodeType element corresponds to each individual line.

The information you want to parse, the file names and versions, are called *attributes* which pertain to the element on each line, so as you read through that sample code in the second link, note how you can extract attributes from each element.

In your case, those two terms are enough to easily parse this file using the existing methods.

In terms of placing these into a dictionary, you might simply use a Dictionary, though since you're familiar with that name you might already be aware of that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx